# How to load class on Android without dex

Tags: java, android, dex

I am trying to load .jar file compiled without android SDK (so classes are not merged to dex). I spent lot of hours trying all possible ways (Javassist, system default class loader...) and just now I found that I need to use DexClassLoader but (logically) it can load only dexed classes. Is there possible way to load non-dexed class? Basically I think no because Android is running on Dalvik which can run only dex.

I used

```
URLClassLoader child = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{file.toURI().toURL()}, BotLoader.class.getClassLoader());
return Class.forName(className, true, child);
```

but this worked only classes inluded or compiled with project.

I also used

```
DexClassLoader classLoader = new DexClassLoader(
                pathToJar, tmp.getAbsolutePath(), null, BotLoader.class.getClassLoader());
        return classLoader.loadClass(className);
```

but I have no idea how to get `optimizedDirectory`.

If I can't use non-dexed classes, can someone please tell me how can I dex my existing classes (.class in .jar) into new jar package?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I ended up with command

```
cd "C:\Android_Studio\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.3"
dx --dex --output="C:\Users\Intel i5\Desktop\ExamplePlugin\out\artifacts\plugin_main_jar\classes.dex" "C:\Users\Intel i5\Desktop\ExamplePlugin\out\artifacts\plugin_main_jar\plugin_main.jar"
```

which generates classes.dex and I manually add them to plugin_main.jar. I tried it in app and it works.

In app, I used:

```
final File tmpDir = new File(activity.getCacheDir().toString());

tmpDir.mkdirs();

DexClassLoader classLoader = new DexClassLoader(
        pathToJar, tmpDir.getAbsolutePath(), null, BotLoader.class.getClassLoader());
return classLoader.loadClass(className);
```

Code `activity.getCacheDir()` does the trick for optimizedDirectory.